# Flyback converter design using the LM5021

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, converter

I'm trying to design a 24V output flyback converter using the LM5021 (with rectifier and filters included). This 24V will be used in a buck converter to decrease to 0-12V 3A with one transformer or 6A with both transformers connected. I've managed to make this work using simulations but I'm not sure if the circuit shown below will work in practice:

- I think my Pi filter after the rectifier might be too overkill? I've seen most designs use like one 100uF capacitor, but testing this on a resistor gave me a pretty big ripple
- Vin stabilizer might use too many components, which increases BOM costs. It keeps it stable though.
- A lot will probably be asking why I added a second transformer: The reason for this is cause I want to be able to increase the current by adding a module and I figured the transformer was probably gonna be the most costly (now still only a transformer with Schottky's). I'm kinda curious how much influence this has on the snubber circuit and output filter though?
- Solar panel controller is not that important at the moment, but I'm trying to be able to either use a solar panel controller (24V output - Schottky diode voltage drop) or the flyback controllers (24V output). Since I'm not using them both at same time some voltage loss from diode doesn't matter for my application. I'm wondering I there's a circuit to automatically disconnect when the solar panel controller has voltage over it (was thinking just a MOSFET tbh)?

**General question**: Is there anything wrong about this circuit in the real world and will the double transformer configuration work? Also is there anything that is overdesigned and can be cut to reduce the costs?

Most of these components are not the ones I'm using on PCB (M1 will probably be a IPD70R600P7S*, transformer used will be the same 750343004 WE)
If anything I said above doesn't make sense or you need more information let me know! Thanks!

[image]

Comment: _"0-12V 3A with one transformer or 6A with both transformers connected"_ Then your transistor was 100% overdesigned in 3A configuration. Strange design choice. _"I think my Pi filter aftrer the rectifier might be too overkill? I've seen most designs use like one 100uF condensator"_ It's capacitor in English. Are you from Europe somewhere where the German word kondensator is used? As for the filter, I suggest you simulate it. Below 10 MHz LTspice is close to reality if you include realistic parasitics.

Comment: What is your question. I quickly scanned but didn't see one.

Comment: @winny you're talking about the MosFet M1? And you mean overdesigned as in i can go for lower current rated one? I'm from Netherlands so i kinda brainfarted there on the translations haha. EDIT: sorry for the bad text, see you've had to fix alot of my grammar...

Comment: You can parallel these types of transformer but don't expect double the power throughput. To answer the first part of the question requires extensive analysis and data sheet links with a schematic that doesn't overlap text making it unreadable. But, in short, nobody is going to go into this on your behalf because it's just far too much work for no return.

Comment: I definitly get what you mean @Andyaka, i updated a clearer picture. I'm not really looking for someone to recheck everything for me though (hate asking questions like: whats wrong with x). But it would be nice if there's people that have input on anything basically (havent been able to test this except in the simulations, so maybe there's some tips and tricks i've missed)

Comment: Check it against this diagram (page 13) in the rev C version of the data sheet: https://datasheet.octopart.com/LM5021MMX-2-Texas-Instruments-datasheet-10847088.pdf - there may be something that you can glean or use.